# McAfee Security locked out of my LGL33L

Tags: security, locked-out, lg-g3

Is there a way around this security lock? I'm not sure if the phone is rooted or not. Is there anything I can use to flash a new rom or firmware/software or something. I have android studio an my laptop I don't know much about it but I wanna learn. Is there a way to use android studio to bypass this security lock?